# Cant get sometimes api.linkedin.com

Tags: ssl, curl

We have some problem when we trying get  curl -vvv 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/'
From 5 request we get 4. Its problem only from subnetwork 109.72.148.0/22 . Could you see your firewall or that the block our request ? 
For Example:

> curl -vvv 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/'
>
> - About to connect() to api.linkedin.com port 443 (#0)
> - Trying 185.63.147.12... connected
> - Connected to api.linkedin.com (185.63.147.12) port 443 (#0)
> - Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
> - CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt 
>      CApath: none 
>     NSS error -5990
> - Closing connection #0
> - SSL connect error 
>    curl: (35) SSL connect error

Comment: There are some ideas ?

Comment: I hope you remember on my problem. Thanks